# Parsing script in node js using node-html-parser

Tags: node.js, parsing

I'm making a script using node.js and i need to parse a script inside a website, exactly i need 2 part not only the entire script. The 2 parts are **"stock"** and **"local" and their values.**

```
<script id="z-vegas-pdp-props" type="application/json">


![CDATA[{
            "layout": "cover",
            "model": {
                "layout": "cover",
                "priceInfo": {
                    "showPriceHint": false,
                    "priceHintType": ""
                },
            "mediaInfo": {
                "currentIndex": 0
            },
                    
            "price": {
                "currency": "EUR",
                "value": 129.99,
                "formatted": "129,99 €"
            },
            "originalPrice": {
                "currency": "EUR",
                "value": 129.99,
                "formatted": "129,99 €"
            },
            "available": false,
            "stock": 0
        }
        //here the scripts continues but i "trimmed it to make it more easy"
    </script>
```

This is what i made but it's parsing all the code and not only the parts that i need.

```
let root = HTMLParser.parse(response.body);
    let availabiltyDiv = root.querySelector("#z-vegas-pdp-props")
    console.log(availabiltyDiv)
```

Answer (score 1):

The data you're looking for is hiding in json format inside the `CDATA` in the script. So you first need to extract the json string, parse it and get to the target data. Incidentally, the json string sample in your question is malformed, but is presumably well formed in the actual script. Also, there is no `local` in your sample, so I'll use another value instead.

All in all:

```
const jstring = availabiltyDiv.childNodes[0].nodeValue.split('CDATA[')[1].split(']')[0]
const target = JSON.parse(jstring);

#to get to (for example) price and stock:
const price = target.model.price.formatted;
const stock = target.model.stock;

console.log(price,stock)
```

Output:

```
"129,99 €" 0
```

EDIT:

As expalined in the respoinse to your comment, I don't have access to your actual `availabilityDiv` but you can also try replacing

```
const jstring = availabiltyDiv.childNodes[0].nodeValue.split('CDATA[')[1].split(']')[0]
```

with

```
const jstring = availabiltyDiv.innerHTML.split('CDATA[')[1].split(']')[0]
```

or with

```
const jstring = availabiltyDiv.innerText.split('CDATA[')[1].split(']')[0]
```

and see if they work.

Comment: i get this error: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at...
how can i fix it?

Comment: @DennyVidotto As I said, the json in your question is malformed and I had to fix it to get the answer. To be able to do it with the real `<script>` content, you'll have to post the whole `availabilityDiv` which is probably too long. You can also try the suggestions in the edit in the answer.

Comment: when i replace them i get: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
btw when i log the availabilityDiv i get this if this will be useful: <ref *1> HTMLElement {
parentNode: HTMLElement {
parentNode: HTMLElement {
parentNode: [HTMLElement],
childNodes: [Array],
nodeType: 1,
rawTagName: 'x-wrapper-pdp',
},
childNodes: [ [HTMLElement], [Circular *1], [HTMLElement] ],
rawAttrs: '',
nodeType: 1,
rawTagName: 'div',
//more lines
childNodes: [
TextNode {
parentNode: [Circular *1],
childNodes: [],
nodeType: 3,
 _rawText: '<![CDATA[{"layout":"cover","model":{"layout": //keep going